# How to validate a spinner in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to validate a spinner in C# in xamarin in visual studio if the user didn't select an option. similar to setError in TextView, I have seen examples in SO but all of them are for java if I'm not wrong.

This is my spinner

```
Spinner spinnerJobTypes = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerJobTypes);
```

and this does not work for me

```
TextView errorText = (TextView)mySpinner.getSelectedView();
```

I would like to display this, if the user hasn't selected anything

[image]

```
            else if (spinnerJobTypes.SelectedItem.ToString() == "-Select-")
            {
                //Display validation error
            }
```

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: I always check for the current spinner value, when the spinner has a list of objects, the default value for "unselected" set it to -1 or 0. If you choose to test by text is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinnerJobTypes = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerJobTypes);
spinnerJobTypes.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs> (spinner_ItemSelected);

private void spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;

            string toast = string.Format ("The planet is {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition (e.Position));
            Toast.MakeText (this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show ();
    }
```

for reference `https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/spinner/`

**Edited:**
Use this and check

```
errorText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.errorIcon, 0);
```

Comment: I'm looking for spinner validation,

Comment: you get value inside that spinner_ItemSelected method. you can validate using that string value.

Comment: Sorry let me edit the question a little bit. I think it's not clear

Comment: Thanks Lingeshwaran, where did you get the errorText? Is it a TextView from the mySpinner? because I can't use TextView errorText = (TextView)mySpinner.getSelectedView(); it gives me an error

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late reply Lingeshwaran. Actually error was because I wrote (TextView)mySpinner.SeletedView(); then I removed (). and it was fine. But I can't see the error message or the drawable icon. I can see the process stops submits but I can't see any validation messages

Comment: @KMR how you set the adapter for spinnerJobTypes ? can u show that code? 
are you using custom layout or not?

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is, add an "None selected" view to the Spinner and use a bool parameter to identify whether user has selected certain item or not:

SpinnerAdapter.cs

```
public class SpinnerAdapter : BaseAdapter<String>
{
    Context context;
    List<String> list;
    public SpinnerAdapter(Context c, List<String> list)
    {
        context = c;
        this.list = list;
    }
    public override string this[int position] => list[position-1];

    public override int Count => this.list.Count+1;

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view;
        if (position == 0)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.spinner_error,null);
            var txtView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvErr);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvErr).Text = "None Selected";
            //uncomment the following line if you want to show the error icon inside of spinner
            //view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvErr).Error = "";
        }
        else
        {
            view = convertView;
            if (view == null|| view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvItem)==null)
            {
                view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.spinner_item, null);
            }
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvItem).Text = list[position-1];

        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Spinner mSpinner;
    bool validatePass=false;
    TextView tvResult;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        mSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.mSpinner);
        var list = InitList();
        SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, list);
        tvResult = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvResult);
        mSpinner.Adapter = adapter;
        mSpinner.ItemSelected += MSpinner_ItemSelected;
    }

    private void MSpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        //use validatePass to indicate if user has selected something.
        if (e.Position != 0)
        {
            validatePass = true;
        }
        else
        {
            validatePass = false;
        }
        tvResult.Text ="Validate Result: "+ validatePass.ToString();
    }

    private List<string> InitList()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            list.Add("Item: " + i);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

But if you really want to show the error icon inside the spinner, you can set the `TextView.Error` inside of `GetView`.

Here is my complete Demo:[HelloSpinner](https://github.com/elvisxia/HelloSpinner).